# Why was my max_children reset on server restart?

Tags: linux, php-fpm

A week ago, I modified my `/etc/php-fpm.conf` file and changed

```
pm.max_children = 215
```

to

```
pm.max_children = 130
```

Last night, I scheduled a reboot and this morning, when I came in we were again at `215`. Why was this reset? Do I need to change this somewhere else to make sure it stays?

Comment: There's nothing in vainilla linux distros which changes the files in /etc Even package managers are instructed to respect user made changes. These files are meant for system configuration. Prevent modifications on those files will be prevent configuration. it's pointless

Comment: Please give us more information about your setup, OS, etc... How did you install php-fpm? Did you have any packages updates? Do you use etckeeper?